# Why does calculation of integral through Riemann and Lesbesgue concept match though the sets are different?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

I know that every Riemann integrable function is Lebesgue integrable but I am confused why these two distinct approaches give equal answers for Riemann integrable functions.

The root of my concern comes from the fact that the sets we integrate over itself is different in Lebesgue integration. We are integrating over sets which are measurable, so, how can it be that we get equal integrals even though we integrate over different sets?

Comment: Both are attempting to measure the same area, the Lebesgue integral is more general.

Comment: Hmm I get that kein problem..

Comment: The Lebesgue integral allows the domain to be sliced in much finer ways, but for 'nice' functions the integrals agree.

Comment: Good point. That helps a bit. I was hoping something more deeper tho

Comment: _When_ we say the same functions are integrable we're restricting attention to functions with a particular domain, maybe $\Bbb R$ or $[0,1]$.

Comment: The strength of the Lebesgue integral isn't so much that we can integrate functions that Riemann could not. That strength is rather the fact that some quite strong limit theorems (monotone convergence and dominated convergence) exist which lead to a closer space of inegrable functions.